# Grow flex columns in height but keep width fixed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two columns to take up 70% and 30% of the page width respectively. I would like them to grow vertically as more elements get added (and wrapped vertically as well).

But I can't get it to behave like that using `flex` as below. If one column grows, while the other remains the same, the growing column overwhelms the smaller one and pushes it into another row.

Any advice?

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left_column {
  flex: 1 1 70%;
}

.right_column {
  flex: 1 1 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left_column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <div>
      <button class="button b1"></button>
      <button class="button b1"></button>
      <button class="button b1"></button>
      <button class="button b1"></button>
      <button class="button b1"></button>
      <button class="button b1"></button>
      <button class="button b1"></button>
      <button class="button b1"></button>
      <button class="button b1"></button>
      <button class="button b1"></button>
      <button class="button b1"></button>
      <button class="button b1"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column right_column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your only error is to add display flex to the `.row`. No need to use vw units

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i understand it right, this should help you.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

.row{
  display:flex;
}

.left_column{
  width:70vw;
}

.right_column{
  width:30vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="column left_column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
          <div>
            <button class="button b1"></button>
            <button class="button b1"></button>
            <button class="button b1"></button>
            <button class="button b1"></button>
            <button class="button b1"></button>
            <button class="button b1"></button>
            <button class="button b1"></button>
            <button class="button b1"></button>
            <button class="button b1"></button>
            <button class="button b1"></button>
            <button class="button b1"></button>
            <button class="button b1"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column right_column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
          <h2>Column 2</h2>
          <p>Some text..Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between ```70vw``` and ```70%```?

Comment: Oh sry, forgot to mention. vw and vh are responsive values in CSS they mean "viewpoint width and viewpoint height. its like a percentage value for your window/screen size. For example when youre window is currently 800px wide, 100vw will have the same value as 800px, and 50vw will have a 400px value. Its an absolute value and perfect for aligntment. But when you use the rows and columns inside another element, you should use percentage, because it use the percentage of the given space

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your CSS should be

```
`.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px; 
}

.left_column {
  flex: 1 1 70%;
}

.right_column {
  flex: 1 1 30%;
}`
```

Because your outer container is the "row" class. After that you can also add "display: flex" to the columns(to left_column and right_column classes here.). I recommend reading this practical [flexbox guide by CSSTricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thanks. If I may follow up with another question: how do I make the two columns grow independently? The CSS above (and from Raqha) make both columns grow to the same height (of the highest column). What if I want them to grow based on their own number of elements?

Comment: You may try this for your css. Also add some more button and text to see the change.:                                                                                      
    `.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px; 
}

.left_column {
  flex: 1 1 70%;
  display: flex;
}

.right_column {
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}`